# Discontinuous convex function over an open convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, continuity

I’d like examples of discontinuous convex functions $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$, where $\Omega$ is on open convex subset of a real vector space, $E$.

And the “more” discontinuous the better.

Comment: If $E$ is finite dimensional,  $f$ will be continuous. Any discontinuous linear functional will do.

Comment: just an aside, you need to specify a topology on $E$ when talking about continuity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimensional space convex functions on open sets are necessarily continuous. Rockafellar's book has  a proof. In an infinite dimensional normed linear space there exist discontinuous linear functionals. These are very 'badly' discontinuous and very 'nicely' convex.

Comment: Thanks. What about non linear examples?

Comment: @user384617: take the square of such a discontinuous linear functional

Comment: Are there "constructive" discontinuous convex functions on open sets in Banach spaces, whose existence does not rely on the axiom of choice?